# Problem with reading pasted text in terminal

Tags: python, terminal

I'm reading text in terminal with
`description = raw_input()`
It works if I write the text and press enter. The problem is when I paste the text from somewhere with `Ctrl+Shift+V` or with `right click + paste`. My program immediately ends, `description` contains only part of the text (I can see it in database).

Do you know how to do this so `paste` works? I'm using `xfce4-terminal` in Ubuntu.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, lifted it from a google search. You have to enter 3 blank lines after your paste, but of course, if there are 3 blank lines in your paste, then it won't work. The concept is there though, you just need to pick an end control character. Thanks for the comments catching that guys.

```
print "paste quote:"
emptycount = 0
lines = []

while emptycount < 2:
    t = raw_input()
    if len(t) == 0:
        emptycount +=1
    else:
        emptycount=0
        lines.append(t)
        lines.append("\n")

print " ".join(lines[:-1])
```

Comment: @xralf: That all depends on how many embedded newlines your pasted text contains.

Comment: @Ignacio I thought that after while cycle in the `lines` list there will be exactly two '\n' in the end, but I see now that there will be three because we're counting from zero :-) Or not? `< 2` => 0 and 1 => lines[:-2] ?

Comment: Actually [:-1] seems to output the best results. It would likely be better to look for some non-newline character to signify the end of the paste, but this is the only way to really accomplish this that I could find.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your pasted text doesn't contain any embedded control characters (such as a newline), which could end the input.